# How to Report a Salesforce Issue

Tags: reporting, bug, filters

While creating report in Salesforce, we can add the date filter to filter the records.

[image]

This is allowing **from date** as today and **to date** as past date. The Salesforce should throw validation error in this case.

I would like to add this in Salesforce known issues in the link http://success.salesforce.com/issues_index.

Anyone please help me how to add this to salesforce issues.

Answer (score 12):

If you click on 'Learn More' top left of the [Issues page](http://success.salesforce.com/issues_index) it will take you to the Issues FAQ.

> What Can I do If I Do Not See My Issue Here? How Can I Report a New
>   Issue?
>
> [Contact Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTPortalLogCase) if you have questions about an Issue
>   affecting your Organization which is not listed here.

Comment: Note that you often have to explicitly request an escalation to tier 3 as they're the only folks who can put an issue on the known issues site.

Answer (score 0):

How to create a Support Ticket in Salesforce?

1. Go to Contact Salesforce Support if you have questions about an Issue affecting your Organization which is not listed here.
   https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTPortalLogCase
2. Login using the appropriate login details.
3. In the Right header click on the Profile picture and choose My Cases.
4. Now you will see a Case Management page, In the Left Sidebar choose 'Create a Case'.
5. In the **Help Finder** Page click on appropriate Topic. Then choose the Category.
6. Now check whether your question in present in the Question section. If not, Create a new Case by scrolling the page below and clicking on **'Log a New Case.**' button.
7. After you will receive the response from the team based on your support question.