# Creating a Class in Dev Console Gives a 500 Error

Tags: developer-console

I am able to create the class in my browser and then edit it in the dev console, but I'm not sure why it won't let me create a class directly from the console.

Comment: You may need to connect salesforce support.This looks like purely salesforce issue .

Comment: 500 is the HTTP code for an Internal Sever Error. Which means something unexpected and prolly nasty happened. I would retry it and see if it works, or if it was just a temporary issue.

Comment: Is there an error code (besides 500)? Including that with the case you file will help support debug the issue.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a server issue. If you could file a case we could get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this seems like a server issue.

You can follow the steps to [submit an issue here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1426/260)