# How can we get "Developer" bugs logged with Technical Support?

Tags: apex, platform-bug

I recently found a bug, which I mentioned on [The Force.com Discussion Boards](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Bug-with-String-join/td-p/656545), as well as submitting a case, and after a few days fumbling around with the case, they closed it by saying that they only provide this type of support for Premier Support customers.

Is there a better channel for reporting bugs than by submitting a case, or is there something "special" we have to do? I realize this question is similar to [reporting - How to Report a Salesforce Issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/how-to-report-a-salesforce-issue), except that I've already gone the route of [Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index), as suggested by the answer there (i.e. submitting a case), to no avail.

How can I make sure that a bug like this can find its way to someone capable of at least confirming that the behavior was expected? This behavior isn't documented anywhere, and so I assume that it's a bug that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @metadaddy  is the man you need to bug.

Comment: I have no idea how message users directly, though, not that I'd want to be a bother. I just find it annoying that every time I submit a bug, they ignore me.

Comment: I hear your pain. Its been ages since I even considered opening up a case with salesforce. Someone from Tier1 talks all day and comes back and says "Unable to replicate". This goes on and on but never is the case solved.

Comment: This was a recent change to the support structure, and it's a REALLY frustrating move by Salesforce. The other day I had a pretty simple case closed without a response because as a partner we don't pay for developer support. Partners and customers shouldn't have to pay extra to be able to report legitimate bugs and request simple support tasks. Anyway, I forwarded your post to the Apex PM.

Comment: Thanks for that. I really appreciate it, join would be so much more efficient that way.

Comment: 3 years and a few months later and everything is still the same.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would suggest posting the issue you found here as a question and then using other channels to get Salesforce people to take a look at it. I've found Twitter especially useful for bringing issues to people's attention. There are also several Salesforce employees lurking here on StackExchange.

Comment: +1 for Twitter now probably being the best place to get somewhat capable/senior SFDC staff to look at your issues. If SFDC invested as much into case management staff as they do into social media monitoring staff we'd all be happier :)

Answer (score 35):

This is the single most frustrating aspect of working with Salesforce. I work for a Salesforce  partner, and we only have basic support. We cannot justify spending $30,000 annually on premier support, when it is something we think should be provided for free (especially for partners).

During the course of my work with the Salesforce platform, I have discovered 10+ bugs, both big and small. And every single time dealing with support has been an arduous and painful experience.

**Know Whats Required**
When logging a case it is absolutely imperative that you grant login access and give the rep the org Id where you have found the bug. If it is a sandbox or developer org  I also give written permission upfront that they are authorized to make changes to the org for testing purposes.

**Know the Hierarchy**

- Tier One: The first line of support. Very basic knowledge of the platform. I have strong suspicions this is outsourced.
- Backline Support: This is who you want looking at your bug. These guys are great, they know the platform and have lots of common sense, if your bug report is well written they will be very helpful in either finding a workaround or escalating further.
- R&D: You will never have direct contact with this tier, these are the actual Salesforce developers who will (eventually) fix your problem

**Be Concise**
My general rule of thumb is; make sure your pet goldfish can understand the problem. Try to make the repro as short and as clear as possible, a 4-5 line unit test or code sample is about the limit of a Tier One rep's understanding. This has a really great side effect which is that it sometimes helps you uncover that the issue is not a bug, but your code (I'm guilty of this more than once :) )
Another effective strategy is request a goto meeting with the Tier One rep, I have found they understand the problem very quickly if you walk them through it.

**Be Persistent**
It is Tier One's job to shield Backline support from menial support issues, as such they will make excuses, close your cases and generally try to fob you off. If your case is closed but you know it's a bug open another case referencing the original case number, kick up a stink and explain that you know it's a bug, and that basic support is mandated to support bugs.

**Escalate, Escalate, Escalate**
You know it's a bug, you know that Tier One can not ever help you. So push the rep straight away to escalate this to Backline support. They will refuse and give excuses but keep pushing. The one non negotiable requirement they have is that the Tier One rep is able to reproduce the issue.

**Get a Resolution**
All but once, I have been told: *This is a known issue, with no eta for a fix.* So make sure you get the issue into the known issue tracker. This will not be volunteered, you will need to request it specifically. I use the reason that it's easier for me to track.

**Be Patient**
Before logging a case remind yourself you will get frustrated and you will be ignored. Basic logic and reasoning will fall on deaf ears. With patience and perseverance you will get through to someone who can help you.
If all else fails you can drown sorrows at Dreamforce with others who have also experienced your pain.

Comment: We have premier support and experience the same frustrations so that is not an answer either. And on more than one occasion our request to post an accepted bug on the known issues site has been refused.

Comment: @KeithC sounds like your getting ripped off... for $30k they could pay someone to sit there and manage your tickets

Answer (score 5):

ceo@salesforce.com - Someone regularly read this, and, in my experience, pretty quickly.

Don't abuse it, but they would not publish the address if they did not want customer contact.

Comment: You know... I've never actually considered emailing Marc. I know that he reads the important stuff, and he's handed it out at Dreamforce, etc, I just never thought my problems were big enough to warrant his attention. On the flip side, though, you have a point. Support is salesforce.com's public relations division (the "front lines"), so these sorts of problems should be addressed if warranted. I might just send him an email and ask. Couldn't hurt, right?

Comment: Did you send said email to Marc? If yes, did you get a reply?

Answer (score -6):

we are more than glad to help you on the developer forums. For questions or issues that end up being platform issues (bugs).

Please post them here: http://boards.developerforce.com/sforce/?category.id=developers

We have employees that work on these boards and its intended use are for these type of issues.

thanks,

Brian Estebez
Senior Manager
Technical Support
Salesforce.com

Comment: I never get even a single forum reply and/or private message there, unless it's someone wanting my help. I've always used the forums to try and get answers (only recently ran into this SE forum, and it seems more lively than the forums proper).

Comment: @brian-estebez. It's great that you've taken the time to post here. I get that Salesforce has it's own official forum for handling issues and bug reports and that splitting your support over multiple sites isn't desirable. Without getting into why SFSE exists - Is there any chance that said employees could also check the StackExchange sites periodically? There are 7000+ Salesforce questions split between StackOverflow and SFSE.

Comment: Expecting developers to log bugs through the forum is simply not good enough, and quite frankly offensive. A forum is not a bug tracker. There is no obligation or incentive from your (Salesforce's) side to investigate or verify the bug. There is a complete lack of traceability or stewardship, no acknowledgment or verification its a bug, no point of contact, no eta on a fix. I could go on.
When logging a bug I am freely donating my time to making your platform better. How is this not in Salesforce best interests? Help us help you, and you will have plenty of happy developers